# PHP using include_path with filesize to avoid Warning: filesize(): stat failed for

Tags: php, fopen, filesize, include-path

In php, I know I can use `include_path` with `fopen`, but I don't see a way to use it with `filesize`. The following code results in an error message...

```
ini_set('include_path', '.:/home/user/lib:../../../lib');

const MY_FILE = 'myfile.txt';

$myFile = fopen(MY_FILE, "r", true) or die("Unable to open file!");
$myFileSize = filesize(MY_FILE);
$myFileContent = fread($myFile, $myFileSize);
echo $myFileContent;
fclose($myFile);
```

The error...

```
Warning: filesize(): stat failed for myfile.txt in /Volumes/...
```

The edit below works, but I don't like having to set the same paths manually and redundantly.

```
ini_set('include_path', '.:/home/user/lib:../../../lib');

const MY_FILE = 'myfile.txt';

$myFile = fopen(MY_FILE, "r", true) or die("Unable to open file!");
if (file_exists("/home/user/lib/" . MY_FILE)) {
  $myFileSize = filesize("/home/user/lib/" . MY_FILE);
} elseif (file_exists("../../../lib/" . MY_FILE)) {
  $myFileSize = filesize("../../../lib/" . MY_FILE);
}
$myFileContent = fread($myFile, $myFileSize);
echo $myFileContent;
fclose($myFile);
```

Suggestions for improvement?

Option 1) Implementing suggestion by @kmoser...

```
ini_set('include_path', '.:/home/user/lib:../../../lib');
$paths = explode(":", get_include_path());

const MY_FILE = 'myfile.txt';

$myFile = fopen(MY_FILE, "r", true) or die("Unable to open file!");
foreach ($paths as $value) {
  if (file_exists($value . "/" . MY_FILE)) {
    $myFileSize = filesize($value . "/" . MY_FILE);
    break; // Stop searching after we find first matching file
  }
}
$myFileContent = fread($myFile, $myFileSize);
echo $myFileContent;
fclose($myFile);
```

Bonus: I like this version suggested by @AlexHowansky in case we simply want to read the file...

```
ini_set('include_path', '.:/home/user/lib:../../../lib');

const MY_FILE = 'myfile.txt';

$myFileContent = get_file_contents(MY_FILE, true);
echo $myFileContent;
```

Comment: If you're just dumping the file, you don't need to know the size -- use https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents  or https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php

Comment: You can avoid checking for other paths by prefixing `./`. So use `const MY_FILE = './myfile.txt';` instead.

Comment: Split `include_path` into an array and loop through all the paths to find your file.

Comment: @MarkusZeller - Thank you, but I'm not trying to avoid checking for other paths in this case.

Comment: @kmoser - Thanks. Perhaps that would be better.

Comment: I added a call to `break;` after finding the first match. This speeds up your code in case there are many folders. However, you may want to handle it differently if there are multiple matching files.

Comment: I’m not trying to judge you in any way, but would you be willing to share why you’d want such a thing in the first place? As noted, there shouldn’t be a reason to know the size of the file in order to dump it. I personally wish the include path system was entirely removed for rootkit reasons, but no one seems to care/agree, and I understand and respect the convenience of a shared codebas

Comment: @ChrisHaas - When I researched how to read from a file I encountered ```fread``` in the PHP documentation. "Example #1 A simple fread() example" shows using ```filesize``` to read the entire contents of the file. After what I've learned from this thread, I'm unlikely to approach it that way.

Comment: @chillywilly, you are absolutely right in regards to the fread example, and it isn't wrong, I think most of us would probably just use `file_get_contents` which does it all. My actual question in the comment was more about using include paths for things that you want to read. I think most people isolate their "stuff" to their project so it is weird to see looking for "stuff" in several locations. Once again, not wrong, just unexpected.